# Save file from ModelForm's FileField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to upload file using the file input in the model creation page in the Django's admin panel. The file isn't a part of an object, so it doesn't belong to an object itself. I just need to get it, process it and then delete it.

I've created a form:

```
class AddTaskAndTestsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tests_zip_field = forms.FileField(required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # I need to save and process the tests_zip_field file here
        return super(AddTaskAndTestsForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = Problem
```

And I added the form to the admin panel, so it's now displayed there.

I need to save the file, once the create form is submitted, but how do I do that?

**UPDATE:** here's how I use it.

*admin.py*:

```
class ProblemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AddTaskAndTestsForm

    fieldsets = [
        # ... some fieldsets here
        ('ZIP with tests', {
            'fields': ['tests_zip_field']
        })
    ]

    # ... some inlines here
```

Comment: Have you looked at the part of the documentation involving [forms and files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)?  You need to make sure that the form is multipart in the html: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">` and that the instantiation of the form in the view is getting both parts of the request: `f = ContactFormWithMugshot(request.POST, request.FILES`.  It's possible that without that, the form just isn't getting the files passed to the view.

Comment: more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: @MBrizzle that's not a form which I put into some page on the website. It's a form for creating a model in 'Admin Panel' (as I stated in my question). So it's not the way

Comment: Working in the admin system doesn't lock you out of accessing the request info.  All of the admin views are perfectly extendable, which allow you to access the requests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods.  The templates are as well -- just overwrite the change_form.html template in your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class AddTaskAndTestsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tests_zip_field = forms.FileField(required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(AddTaskAndTestsForm, self).save(commit=False)
        f = self['tests_zip_field'].value() # actual file object
        # process the file in a way you need
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. Works just great. Can you please add a link to the specific docs article, where everyone could read this?

Comment: I found solution just through browsing django's source code, so I am not sure if it's documented anywhere. I am glad it helped you, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can call tests_zip_field.open() ( behaves pretty much like the python open() ) and use it in your save() method like this :

```
tests_zip_file = self.tests_zip_field.open()
tests_zip_data = tests_zip_file.read()
## process tests_zip_data 
tests_zip_file.close()
```

the file is saved in your MEDIA_ROOT/{{upload_to}} folder whenever the save() method finishes

Comment: When I try to use `tests_zip_file = tests_zip_field.open()` I get an exception saying 'There's no global tests_zip_field'. If I use it like this `tests_zip_file = self.tests_zip_field.open()`, then I get an exception 'self doesn't have an object tests_zip_field' (something like this). So it doesn't work for me.

Comment: its self.tests_zip_field.open(), which version of django are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Django v1.6.6

Comment: You have to set upload_to for this to work, check this out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to